# best practices of separating two dependent sets of data in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design

My application needs two sets of data, and I want to separate it logically on two parts. It's ideal to have namespaces for tables in one instance of mysql database, but I can't find any clues that this feature exists. So, I decided to split data onto two schemas (static & dynamic) in one instance of mysql. Though, my `dynamic` data depends on `static` part, and some of my stored procedures in `dynamic` selects data from `static` database.

What is the best practices to avoid hardcoding schema names in stored procedures, or splitting data in similar way I want?

Answer (score 1):

This is often done with Synonyms, but MySQL does not support that. You didn't say exactly why you wanted to 'logically separate' the data; this could be done by just prefixing the table names with some sort of identifier.   To avoid the hassle of hard-coding schema names I suggest rethinking separating the tables.